# Unable to install dev-dependency in node 0.10.x Error: No compatible version found:

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install, package.json

I am trying to run an old node project with node version as "0.10.x" and npm version as "1.4.x".
I created a nodenv which has node version as 0.10.9 and npm version as 1.2.24

The project has a dev-dependency of     `"load-grunt-tasks": "~0.6.0"`.

But when I am trying npm install using `npm install load-grunt-tasks@~0.6.0`, I am getting the following errors:

```
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: multimatch@'^0.3.0'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.1.0","0.2.0","0.3.0","1.0.0","1.0.1","2.0.0","2.1.0","3.0.0","4.0.0","5.0.0"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/mnt/c/Users/harsh/OneDrive/Documents/ONITO/software-services/hcare/OphthalmoCare-development/env-0.10/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:709:10)
npm ERR!     at /mnt/c/Users/harsh/OneDrive/Documents/ONITO/software-services/hcare/OphthalmoCare-development/env-0.10/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:631:10
npm ERR!     at saved (/mnt/c/Users/harsh/OneDrive/Documents/ONITO/software-services/hcare/OphthalmoCare-development/env-0.10/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:138:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft
npm ERR! command "/mnt/c/Users/harsh/OneDrive/Documents/ONITO/software-services/hcare/OphthalmoCare-development/env-0.10/bin/node" "/mnt/c/Users/harsh/OneDrive/Documents/ONITO/software-services/hcare/OphthalmoCare-development/env-0.10/bin/npm" "install" "load-grunt-tasks@~0.6.0"
npm ERR! cwd /mnt/c/Users/harsh/OneDrive/Documents/ONITO/software-services/hcare/OphthalmoCare-development
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.9
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.24
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /mnt/c/Users/harsh/OneDrive/Documents/ONITO/software-services/hcare/OphthalmoCare-development/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

or sometimes the dependency error gets replaced with

```
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: findup-sync@'^0.1.2'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.1.0","0.1.1","0.1.2","0.1.3","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.3.0","0.4.0","0.4.1","0.4.2","0.4.3","1.0.0","2.0.0","3.0.0","4.0.0"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 0.6.0 of [`load-grunt-tasks`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/load-grunt-tasks?activeTab=versions) is 7 years old, so it's recommended to upgrade it anyway.

It's interesting/strange that it thinks there is no compatible version, even though it literally gives a list of versions, including one that should be compatible. Might be a bug due to using such old NPM version like 1.2.24, as this has been [reported before](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8811) it seems.